# Running into issue with SPFX recently Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'startsWith'

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spf

I am running into below issue when I try configuring SPFX control on Modern Page, this particular control was working fine without any issue up until now.

## Something went wrong

If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details.
Technical Details
[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "11111111-2017-4bc3-9a39-18dfdd167e1b" (DocumentNavigationWebPart).
Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "11111111-2017-4bc3-9a39-18dfdd167e1b" (DocumentNavigationWebPart).
Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/11111111-2017-4bc3-9a39-18dfdd167e1b_0.0.1
 Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'startsWith'

***INNERERROR:
***Failed to load entry point from component "11111111-2017-4bc3-9a39-18dfdd167e1b" (DocumentNavigationWebPart).
Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/11111111-2017-4bc3-9a39-18dfdd167e1b_0.0.1
 Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'startsWith'
***CALLSTACK:
Error
   at t._generateErrorStackForIE (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2019-04-19.008/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-...)
   at t (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2019-04-19.008/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-...)
   at t (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2019-04-19.008/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-...)

Comment: Howdy. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some additional information to your question. To best help you it is important to include your code and any attempts you have made to resolve the issue on your own.

Answer (score 1):

It is a polyfill issue. Please add the below polyfill in the `webpart.js` file ([link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Running-into-issue-with-SPFX-recently-Cannot-redefine-non/td-p/505158)).

```
import 'core-js/es6/string';
```